# Calling Json Web Service using AJAX in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ajax, json, web-services

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The overview:
I have one .Net solution, 2 projects.  One hosts a web service, one calls the web service.
The web service accepts an integer id argument and returns a person name formatted as JSON.
Here is the raw output straight out of Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 16:51:18 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 35
Connection: Close

{"PersonName":"Jane Doe"}
```

Here's the basic Web service set up:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class PeopleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GetUserName(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (EformTstEntities db = new EformTstEntities())
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var jsonData = new
                {
                    PersonName = (from i in db.People where i.ID == ID select i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName).FirstOrDefault()
                };
                string retJSON = js.Serialize(jsonData);
                Context.Response.Write(retJSON);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Context.Response.Write(string.Format("[ERROR: {0}]", ex.Message));
        }

    }
}
```

So, I assume the web service is working fine and not a problem...

Here is my basic call to the web service via ajax.  At this time I am not trying to do anything with the output, I'm just trying to call the web service without an error.  On the call I continually drop into the error handling function.  Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getUserName() {
            var id = $("#UserID").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:1211/Services/PeopleWebService.asmx/GetUserName",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{ID:'" + id + "'}",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("this worked");
                }, 
                error: function () {
                    alert("this error");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: Friendly tip change you error function to this and it should give you more information on the specific error that is occuring:   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
data: "{'ID':'" + id + "'}",
```

and also change the error method to see the error details like below

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    alert(thrownError);
}
```

Comment: 200

    {"PersonName":"Jane Doe"}{"d":null}

    SyntaxError: Syntax error

Comment: @user2887262 are you testing on firefox ? then try on other browser